# How to get callback on blocking webcam by user in Javascript getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, webcam

I starts webcam stream in my web page using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`. I want to get some callback event when user explicitly blocking camera from the tab option ('Pause' on safari & 'Always block camera' option in chrome).
I attached chrome screenshot just to clear the problem.

[image: eChrome option to block camera when]

When user allows permission first time and then blocking camera using above option then there is no event being triggered at my code. I tried searching for such events but did not find anything. I just wanted to show some message to user on blocking the camera. Following is my full code using to start webcam stream.

```js
function startCamera() {
  if (streaming) return;
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
    .then(function(s) {
    stream = s;
    video.srcObject = s;
    video.play();
    console.log("Start camera");
    isCameraCap = true;
  })
    .catch(function(err) {
     //executing when user disallow permission 
    console.log(`Stop camera at error ${err}`);
    console.log("An error occured! " + err);
    isCameraCap = true;
  });

  video.addEventListener("canplay", function(ev){
    if (!streaming) {
      videoWidth = video.videoWidth;
      videoHeight = video.videoHeight;
      video.setAttribute("width", videoWidth);
      video.setAttribute("height", videoHeight);
      canvasOutput.width = videoWidth;
      canvasOutput.height = videoHeight;
      streaming = true;
    }
    startVideoProcessing();
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: Using the same `errorcallback` suggested in this doc, It is triggering when user denies permission but no triggering on blocking after permission is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.onended = () => console.log('stopped'))
```

You can listen to the ['ended' event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/ended_event) once you have the stream.
This will give you a signal that capturing has stopped, without giving you the exact reason (i.e. it could also fire when the user unplugs the webcam)